# Using ckEditor on selective text areas in django admin forms

Tags: django, django-admin, ckeditor

I want to apply ckeditor on specific textarea in django admin form not on all the text areas.

Like snippet below will apply ckeditor on every textarea present on django form:

```
class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    formfield_overrides = 
    {models.TextField: {'widget': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'ckeditor'})}, }

    class Media:
        js = ('ckeditor/ckeditor.js',)
```

but i want it on a specific textarea not on every textarea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have couple of options.

I think the simplest is if you use Django 1.2, then you have to create custom form for your admin and use 'widgets' option:

```
ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm)
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        widgets = { 
           'field_1' : forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'ckeditor'}),
           'field_2' : forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'ckeditor'}),
            ...
        }
```

If you use older version of Django you can still use custom form, just override the field, in which you want ckEditor, in the form:

```
ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm)
    class Meta:
        model = Project

    field_1 = forms.SomeField(label=u'my label', widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'ckeditor'}))
```

Alternative:

```
ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm)
    class Meta:
        model = Project

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['field_1'].widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'ckeditor'})
```

Finally for all three options, you set your ProjectAdmin to use ProjectForm:

```
class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)
    form = ProjectForm
```

Comment: What a thorough answer! You rock!

Comment: Hi Lucasz, Ihave used Django 1.2.7 and django-ckeditor with ckeditor 3.6.3.